# TS3005 Timer End of life...what should I do for an ultra low power astable?

Tags: timer

I am working on a circuit with a Sharp Memory display that requires a VCOM 50% duty cycle square wave signal at a frequency of approx 1Hz.

It was suggested to use a TS3005 ([Datasheet](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/368/TS3005DS-r1p0_Final-Mar-13-336844.pdf))which looked perfect until I see that Silicon Labs has EOL (End of Life) its timers and I cannot seem to get hold of them anymore.

It looks like the whole family of TS3001->TS3006 are being discontinued.

The TS3005 looked perfect because it had an adjustable duty cycle frequency using just a simple Resistor and its Ultra Low Supply Current: 1.35μA at 49Hz.
This is a nice chip because it runs all on its own without CPU intervention.

I looked at the TI TPL5x00 chips but they all seem to need an outside DONE signal, and I wanted my CPU to be completely asleep, while the timer chip refreshes the Memory Display.

I really need something with very low power consumption as it will be running from a coin-cell battery.

Does anyone know of a suitable replacement circuit that performs the same in both duty cycle of 50%, Frequency (1Hz) and very low supply current?

I looked at the 555 timer and the power consumption is way too large.

I am working on something similar to the Chronio watch project [here](https://hackaday.io/project/12876-chronio).

Thanks
Mark

Comment: have you even looked at CMOS low power 555 timers? Texas Instruments has one that uses 100uA  http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmc555.pdf

Comment: you could also try a very low power CMOS oscillator circuit and an ultra-low power comparator to convert the sine wave oscillation into a square wave

Comment: here ya go! http://www.discovercircuits.com/PDF-FILES/astable.pdf

Comment: I am late to the party so you may have found a replacement. Have you looked at the SiT1569 from Si time?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [DS1341/2](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS1341-DS1342.pdf) to generate a 1 Hz signal ...in addition it could be your main crystal controlled timepiece. It draws less than 500 nA @ 3 V.

You could even use the new DS2417 which draws less than 200 nA @ 3 V and the 1-Wire interface is much lower power than I2C.

Since I assume you are using an ATMega328P, the 1 Hz signal can be a wakeup interrupt along with any button presses.
If you are doing something like Chronio you should make sure to read [Gammon](http://www.gammon.com.au/power) and [Morissey](http://donalmorrissey.blogspot.com/2010/04/putting-arduino-diecimila-to-sleep-part.html) on deep sleep with the ATMega328(P), they are very useful research.

Comment: great idea with the RTC and the 1Hz output pulse. I've also seen GPS modules output 1Hz pulses before too